# Sprites not working - Background Position = 50%

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm overlooking something obvious in using my sprites.  I have an example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/HJUg6/1/).
It is not displaying the sprite in the span and when I look at the element in Chrome, it is reporting an actual background position of 0px, 50%.  The css is 0px, -31px.

Suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the SPAN display as block and lose the comma between your background position settings as there should simply be a space:

http://jsfiddle.net/HJUg6/2/

Answer (score 1):

`SPANS` are not block elements, and cannot take on a width or height CSS property. Use a `DIV` or add `display:block` to your definition for this element.

Comment: Thanks for oversight. I've updated the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/HJUg6/4/, However, my original problem still remains. In chrome, when I looked at the Computed Style, it is reporting the background position as 0px, 50%;

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block` on the div and it works. ( I don't know if that's the image that you should see.. )